# findAll() method is giving the empty result set in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

In hibernate I used `findById()` and `findAll()` in Dao layer.`findById()` method working as I expected, but `findAll()` always returns empty result set,I still couldn't figure out the reason, any one could help me to solve this issue,

Note: There is no exception, returns only empty list

Here is my code

Find All method

```
 public List<T> findAll() {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery("SELECT obj FROM " + persistentClass.getSimpleName() + " obj");
        return query.list()
    }
```

Find by Id method

```
public T findById(Long id) {
        T result = (T) getSession().get(getPersistentClass(), id);
        return result;
    }
```

getSession method

```
protected Session getSession() {
        if (session == null)
            session = tenantBasedSessionFactory.getTenantBasedSession("tenantId");
//            throw new IllegalStateException("Session has not been set on DAO before usage");
        return session;
    }
```

Thank you in advance 
Cheers

Comment: What do the SQL logs say. Enable SQL logging and check that the SQL query is the right one.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Here is the sql query
"SELECT obj FROM Employee obj", I think it's a correct,

Comment: I know this is stupid question, but do you have any data in Employee table ? I mean commited data ?

Comment: yes,I couldn't figure out the reason, it's working properly with findById() method

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution to this, Error was in my side, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issues with that, assuming the entity name is accurate and data is present, but did you try the short notation already?

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM " + persistentClass.getSimpleName());
```

I find it better to read for simple 'get all' queries as you don't need any aliases if only one entity is returned.